# python multiline string in a column to row in csv

Tags: python, csv

Need some idea on how to handle this scenario in python 
i am using python version 3.5.2

And i am 2 days old in python skills.

I have a csv file with a multiline string in a column

Example:   I have 3 column and the 3rd column contains multiline strings

**what i have**

```
column1     column2         column3

AppZok |    wendy1  | car one\n bike two\n jeep one
```

[image]

The thrid column contains  whitespace between   car' 'one 
and newlinechar between car one\nbike

And below is what i am expecting the output to be.

**what i need**

```
AppZok  wendy1  car     one
AppZok  wendy2  bike    two
AppZok  wendy3  jeep    one
```

[image]

This is code i have now and i just print the 3rd column. I know this is not the way may be, but i  am keep updating the code by looking for answers

```
import csv
import re
import string

with open('data_post.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines =csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    out_file=open('multi_line_out.csv','w')
    for x in lines :
        #print (x[3])
        data_write=csv.writer(out_file,delimiter='\n')
        #final_data=x[1]
        data_write.writerow(x[2])
```

And i result i get is

```
c
a
r

o
n
e
\
n

b
i
k
e

t
w
o
\
n

j
e
e
p

o
n
e
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you post some code that you've worked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example code can expand a line of your csv file to multiple lines.

```
line = ["AppZok", "wendy1", "car one\n bike two\n jeep one"]

def expand_column(line, col):
    new_rows = map(lambda p: p.strip().split(" "), line[col].split("\n"))
    return map(lambda row: line[:col] + row + line[col+1:], new_rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(expand_column(line, 2)))
```

I think from here on you should be able to do it yourself :)

Comment: Thank you Michael fro your quick response. i just copied your code and test it and  get this msg   C:\\data>python test.py
<map object at 0x0000000000DCD128>

Comment: Ah. You are using python3. I updated my answer to cope with that. In essence, ``list`` forces python to execute the map operation and gather the elements in a list.

Comment: To begin with, you can search for "python lambda" in Google. This should bring up quite a few basic tutorials. A "lambda" is nothing more than a anonymous function: It takes some parameters, does some computation and returns some result. In the case of ``expand_columns`` you start with looking at ``line[col].split("\n")``. This is the list ``["care one", " bike two", " jeep one"]``. ``map`` applies a function to every element of that list. Here it strips the surrounding whitespaces and splits the string again. From here on, just Google if something interests you and ask specific questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Newline characters in CSV are valid characters, there is no escape sequence for them.  You need to interpret those literal `\n` strings as delimiters.  Then split the values and build out your rows.

```
import csv
with open(inpath, 'r') as infile,\
     open(outpath, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        data = line[:-1]
        for last in line[-1].split(r'\n '):
            writer.writerow(data + last.split(' '))
```